# Two UIContainerViews cause loading issue in Swift / iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uicontainerview

I use two containerViews one over another to load inside the same tabBar parent  Page. 
If condition A is true
  set containerA alpha to 1  and container B alpha to 0
If condition B is true
 set  set containerA alpha to 0  and container B alpha to 1

I am  loading a JSON from the server in my viewdidload/viewwillappear  of corresponding childViewControllers which is attached to parent UIViewContainer.  My issue is that whenever I opens the tab, it loads both's childViewcontroller(containerA and containerB) Viewload method .
So it calls both's containers JSON request to server.
Is there a good way to separate this JSON calls ?

Comment: I use UIViewControllers, normally where should we do it? I am newbie in swift/iOS.

Comment: yes, I write the JSON code in my model class, But I have to invoke those methods whenever the page appears.

Comment: I think it  one way to avoid memory issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003602/swift-how-to-link-two-view-controllers-into-one-container-view-and-switch-betw